# How to loop through an array and get the name corresponding to id and assign the result to another array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript .please help me in doing this.
I have an array as below.

```
let pets=[{id:"1",name:"animal"},{id:"2",name:"animal"}];
```

i want to loop through pets and get the names of animals from another array Category where

```
let category = [{id:"1",name:"Dog"},{id:"2",name:"Cats"},{id:"3",name:"Cows"},{id:"4",name:"Goat"}]
```

get output as below,

```
// expected output,
newpets=[{id:"1",name:"Dog"},{id:"2",name:"Cats"}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out. I have used, [Array map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to achieve this.

```js
let pets=[{id:"1",name:"animal"},{id:"2",name:"animal"}];
let category = [{id:"1",name:"Dog"},{id:"2",name:"Cats"},{id:"3",name:"Cows"},{id:"4",name:"Goat"}]

let newPets = pets.map(eachPet => {
  return category.find(eachCat => eachPet.id === eachCat.id)
})

console.log(newPets)
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to do it. One way

```
let pets=[{id:"1",name:"animal"},{id:"2",name:"animal"}];
let Category = [{id:"1",name:"Dog"},{id:"2",name:"Cats"},{id:"3",name:"Cows"}, 
{id:"4",name:"Goat"}];

var newpets = [];

pets.forEach(pet => {
   let animalType = Category.find(cate => pet.id === cate.id );       
   newpets.push({id:pet.id, name: animalType.name});

})

console.log(newpets);
```